# ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment

Tags: ros, environment-variables, ros-package-path, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to set my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable permanently. I appended the following line to the etc/environment file: *ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/zayin/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks"*. Then, I logged out and back in. However, when I type *echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH* in the terminal, I get */opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks*, which is the initial setting. What have I forgotten to do? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62520/ros_package_path-environment/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar questions/answers exist - see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/30586/how-to-change-ros_package_path/), [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/60424/ros_package_path-for-catkin-beginners/).

Unless you add your workspace to the package path in your `~/.bashrc` file, each time you open a new terminal you will need to `source` your workspace (see [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)).

To set your workspace permanently, open your `.bashrc` file in a text editor, for example -- `gedit ~/.bashrc` -- and add

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/your/path/to/workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

at the bottom of your file. Obviously, make sure you change "/your/path/to/workspace" to your exact workspace path..

---

Originally posted by [Souldier](https://answers.ros.org/users/4820/souldier/) with karma: 198 on 2013-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-10**:
Thanks! I got it to work thanks to these topics!

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-01-25**:
I don't understand the last part :$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
Should it be like this ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/hjt/catkin_ws/src:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

**Comment by [bemery94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27151/bemery94/) on 2017-02-05**:
The ":$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" means that you are adding "/home/hjt/catkin_ws/src" to the start of the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, whereas if you just did "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=..." then the new ROS_PACKAGE_PATH would overwrite the existing path.